# C# Dropbox Sync Status

Tags: c#, dropbox-api

I am working on integrating drop box into my C# application. I am trying to retrieve the drop box sync status but I could not find any method in Drop Box API to retrieve the information. There are a number of methods that could be used to retrieve the user information and everything but I could not find any method that would retrieve sync information.

My code is below:

```
//Retrieve dropbox sync state here
//Convert sync state to status code
switch (statusCode)
      {
        case 0:
          return "Not in dropbox";
        case 1:
          return "Sync state upto date";
        case 2:
          return "Synchronizing";
        case 3:
          return "Issue syncing";
        default:
          throw new IOException("Issue communicating with drop box");
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Dropbox API does not offer the ability to check the desktop client sync status, but I'll pass this along as a feature request. I can't promise if or when that might be implemented though.

One exception is that [the Dropbox desktop client on Linux only does support some command line commands](https://help.dropbox.com/installs-integrations/desktop/linux-commands#commands).